# Can the Entity Framework Code First generate properly for System.Drawing.Font or Dictionaries?

Tags: entity-framework, dictionary, ef-code-first

I am trying to generate a CMS using the Entity Framework Code First. I have a TextBox class that I'd like to have a System.Drawing.Font property or a Dictionary Property. Can the Entity Framework Code First generate properly for System.Drawing.Font or Dictionaries?

Answer (score 0):

EF CF is a code-based ORM (Object-Relational Mapper). It handles the storage and retrieval of data held in classes in your app to and from tables in a database.

If you want to store/retrieve data from your forms, you should create "model" classes - these are just simple classes that contain properties for the values you want to store in your DB. For example:

```
public class Page
{
    public Guid ID {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public string Body {get; set;}
    public string FontName {get; set;}
    public int FontSize {get; set;}
}
```

You then create a DbContext class that contains DbSet instances of the type of your model classes:

```
public class StorageContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Page> Pages {get; set;}
}
```

Now, EF will figure out the structure of the data you want to store and handle all the DB operations to load/store your data to your DB.

You should be able to write pretty much all your model and DB code (in a separate library in case you need to reuse).

Note: I also strongly encourage you to add an additional level of abstraction and create a Repository class so that your UI code needs know nothing about HOW you're storing your data - this will allow you to change to a completely different storage engine later without having to touch your app code! For example:

```
public class PageRepo
{
    StorageContext _ctx = new StorageContext();

    public Page GetPageById(Guid id)
    {
        ...
    }

    public void StorePage(Page page)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

You then use your StorageContext (or, better still, your repository) and Model classes to get/store data from/to your DB and copy those values into the necessary fields in your forms, peprforming any data validation before you store data, of course ;)

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework allows you to only map few predefined types. That is because it is an ORM and data types that are common to many RDBMS are supported. You can how ever break the complex type such as `Font` to its primitive properties and map to an entity.

Eg

```
public class Style
{
    public Guid ID {get; set;}
    public string FontName {get; set;}
    public int FontSize {get; set;}
    // other properties
}
```

In your UI layer you would have a `TextBox` that will use the style to build a Font.

```
public class TextBox
{
    public TextBox(Style style)
    {
        Style = style;
    }
    protected Style Style {get; set;}

    public Font FontSize { get { return new Font(Style.FontName, Style.FontSize); } }
    // other properties
}
```